# Recovering a (edmx) Field in a Entity Model

Tags: edmx, recover

I have a SQL Database which I imported as a ADO.NET Entity Data Model. I then proceeded to rename some tables and field names in the model. I quite foolishly deleted the wrong field in my model. It still shows in the SQL table, but not in my model. How can I get it back with out deleting my model and starting over?

Comment: Did you run the "Update Model From Database" wizard? (right click on an empty area in your EDMX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the "Update Model From Database" wizard.
Right click on an empty area in your `EDMX`.